# Limit the number of rows returned from a query in both oracle and postgres

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, jpa

I'm working with JPA Criteria API, and I had a requirement where I have to use `UNION` clause, and since JPA doesn't support set operations, I had to create a native sql query.

In this query I have to limit the number of rows returned, using JPA Criteria API, this was done as following :

```
typedQuery.setFirstResult(gridParams.getStartRow());
typedQuery.setMaxResults(gridParams.getEndRow() - Math.max(0, gridParams.getStartRow()));
```

Our application is running in both Oracle 12c and Postgres, so The problem I faced is that Oracle and Postgres are using different syntax to limit the result.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both database systems support the ANSI standard `fetch first`:

```
select *
from some_table
order by something
OFFSET 10 ROWS
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Oracle started supporting that with 12.1

- [fetch first in the Postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT)
- [fetch first in the Oracle manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABBADDD)

Comment: I have the version 12.1.0.2.0, but when I use this syntax I get the message `SQL command not properly ended`

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki: I forgot the `ROWS` keyword for `OFFSET`. See my edit